# If $f(x)=\cos x$ how do I find $f[(0,\pi)]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Just want to know how to solve problems of this type: if $f(x)=\cos x$ then what is $f([0,\pi])$?

Comment: To display $\pi$ write `$\pi$`.

Comment: $f([0, \pi]) := \{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists x \in [0, \pi], y = \cos x \}$.

Comment: $I=[0,\pi]$ is connected set and $f$ is continuous function, so $f(I)$ is connected set, so we only need to find min and max of $f$  on $I$ and then $f(I)=[\min, \max]$ ($I$ is compact, so $f(I)$ is compact set also, so we have $[\,, \, ]$)

Answer (score 3):

$$f(\pi)=\cos\pi=-1\;\;,\;\;f(0)=\cos 0 = 1$$

and since $\;f\;$ is continuous, applying the IVT we get

$$f(0,\pi)=(-1,1)$$

Comment: I think you mean IVT.

Comment: @DonAntonio With this argument, all you can say is $f([0,\pi])\subset [-1,1]$

Comment: I don't think so, @user37238: by continuity, the image of an interval is an interval, and since we're getting the extreme points (and, of course, the extreme possible values of cosine)  there must be equality.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAlbanese , edited.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Since I don't know what the student can assume, is it safe to assume that cosine doesn't take its max/min on the interior of the interval? Maybe this is what user#### was trying to point out?

Comment: That the fact that the maximal value of sine/cosine is $\;1\;$ is, I think, high school stuff everywhere I know, and since the question seems to be a college/university level one I think we can safely assume the OP knows this, @Clayton .

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't want to stir up any trouble; simply throwing out a suggestion (also why I mentioned I didn't know what we could say the student could assume for the purposes of the class). Also, I wasn't arguing for the max/min of cosine, just the locations of the max/min.

Comment: It's fine @Clayton. No problem stirred at all and thanks for the comments. I don't know what the OP can assume and what not, yet high school stuff seems to be assumable (?) for a student...

Comment: I remember in my class we couldn't assume anything until we had proven it, either on our own for the homework or in class :) Since this was the structure of my class, I try to imagine everyone under such constraints. Glad there aren't any problems.

Comment: @Clayton , this could be a difference of approaches: high schools kids here (Israel) in mathematics Level A and level B both learn about the generalization of the definition of the trigonometric functions from a straight angled triangle to the trigonometric (unity) circle and etc. and, of course, they know (in a perfect world, of course) exactly where the basic trigonometric functions attain their maximum/minimum values. This is not university/college stuff and, I suppose, it can be assumed.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated, however, when I key in cos $\pi$ in my calculator I get .9984971499. I do not get a negative answer. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @CRiddick , most probably your calculator is programmed to *degrees* instead of *radians*...this happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the graph of $\cos(x)$ between $[0, \pi]$, and then project the graph on the $y$-axis.

If you are not familiar with the projection, imagine the sun being somewhere at $\infty$ on the $x$-axis, and you need to find the shadow of the graph on the $y$-axis.